# More CSS toolkits like Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, resources, styles, toolkit, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking for a place where I can find CSS toolkits and resources, ready to be used like the popular [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Any tips?

Comment: I think CSS toolkits with styles for all key "web app" elements like alerts, forms etc is kind of a new thing - if more come out someone will likely create a central hub

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[html5boilerplate](http://www.html5boilerplate.com) is my favoured toolkit

Comment: HTML5 boilerplate is a not a CSS Toolkit, its a template.

Comment: @iRaghu the OP asks for `CSS toolkits and resources` and html5boilerplate is a resource

Answer (score 8):

Yahoo! have recently created [Pure](http://purecss.io/) (source available on [GitHub](https://github.com/yui/pure/)).

Pure provides:

- A CSS Foundation **built upon [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)** so that cross-browser issues are minimised.
- **Styling of common UI components** such as lists, menus, buttons, forms and tables.
- A comprehensive **responsive grid system** for building a site for all devices.

It is ***very lightweight*** with a total footprint of 4.4KB minified and gzipped compared to Bootstrap's 20KB. It is accessible from a CDN that Yahoo! provides.

It has been created with the viewpoint that creating new CSS rules is preferred to overwriting/altering existing ones. Therefore it is shipped with minimal styles out of the box (*hence the size*) - you have to create your own.

Answer (score 7):

[Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) is really great, if you liked bootstrap, you should like it even more!

Answer (score 6):

I think you will find [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php) to be very good as well

Answer (score 3):

[Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) is one of the popular CSS frameworks also.

Answer (score 3):

If a good CSS framework is all you need, [YAML](http://www.yaml.de) is a great alternative too.

Answer (score 3):

Try [skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) as another alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Selection of any UI framework depends on the related technology stack. I use Semantic-UI (http://semantic-ui.com/) with AngularJS. Believe me, they are made for each other!

Semantic-UI gives good support for responsive web design and mobile components.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list of CSS frameworks which you may enjoy working with...

- [base](http://getbase.org/) - Responsive CSS framework with IE7+ support
- [BASSCSS](http://basscss.com/) - Low-level CSS toolkit
- [bootflat](http://bootflat.github.io/) - Bootstrap with a flat design theme
- [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) - A collection of themes for Bootstrap
- [bulma](http://bulma.io/) - CSS framework based on Flexbox
- [cardinal](http://cardinalcss.com/) - Cardinal is a small mobile first CSS framework
- [caramel](http://kurisubrooks.com/caramel/) - A simple, beautiful, responsive, modern CSS framework
- [HTML Starterkit](http://zitrusfrisch.com/html-starterkit/) - HTML5 template to kick off your responsive websites
- [kube](http://imperavi.com/kube/) - Minimalistic Web framework
- [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/) - Material Design Lite Components in HTML/CSS/JS
- [materialize](http://materializecss.com/) - A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design
- [Metro UI](https://metroui.org.ua/) - A front-end framework for developing website in Windows Metro Style
- [milligram](http://milligram.io/) - Minimal setup of styles for a fast starting point.
- [mini.css](http://minicss.org/) - A minimal, responsive, style-agnostic CSS framework/toolkit
- [mui](https://www.muicss.com/) - A Lightweight HTML/CSS/JS Framework implementing Material Design
- [papier](http://gugel.io/papier/) - Material design like minimal CSS framework
- [pavilion](http://www.pavilion.io/) - Unopinionated CSS framework
- [picnicss](http://picnicss.com/) - Lightweight UI library
- [pure](http://purecss.io/) - A set of small, responsive CSS modules
- [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/) - UI Kit with lots of themes and elements
- [skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) - A dead simple, responsive boilerplate
- [tachyons](http://tachyons.io/) - Modular UI framework
- [uikit](http://getuikit.com/) - A lightweight and modular front-end framework

Answer (score 2):

there is another one similar to bootstrap twitter ,  try [HTMLKickStart](http://www.99lime.com/)

Answer (score 0):

See free and extremely liteweight Litestrap CSS toolkit: http://js.plus/products/litestrap

The same as Bootstrap but only the grid (scaffolding).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that:

- has cross-platform styling (iOS, Android, WP, Web)
- can be used with different themes
- is framework agnostic
- you can use it on mobile as well as desktop

Take a look at [Mobiscroll Forms](https://mobiscroll.com/forms).